# Authorized user on Lowe’s credit card (only credit history besides phone bill) how will this affect me when applying for an auto loan?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score, credit-history, auto-loan

I’m 18 with a credit score of ~719. My grandfather added me on his Lowe’s credit card ($8,000 limit). He’s had this credit card for over two years and it shows up on my credit report as if I’ve had it for over 2 yrs as well, even though he just added me to it approximately a month ago.

To be honest I am unsure of whether I am an authorized user or a joint owner ( I am assuming I am an authorized user ).  This is the only credit history I have besides my phone bill that I’ve had for only 2 months.

I was wondering how this would affect my chances of getting a car loan with Navy Federal Credit Union in a couple months? Would they see that I am only an authorized user and decide not to give me a car loan until I establish some other credit?

Comment: Just curious: Does your phone bill appear on your credit report?

Answer (score 4):

Being an authorized user of your grandfather's credit card is undoubtedly boosting your credit score.

We can't know for sure if you will get approved for a car loan, as it could be based on additional information that you put on the loan application, such as your income. But your credit score is pretty good at this point, so your credit score probably won't stop you from getting a car loan. You can ask NFCU what the requirements are for the loan that you are interested in.

That having been said, I would encourage you to think twice before taking out a car loan. Instead, pile up whatever cash you can, get the best used car you can for that price, then start saving up for your next car. Repeat this process until you are buying nice cars for cash. This will save you money in the long run and will avoid some potentially bad financial situations.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use a free app like Credit Karma or get your free annual credit report at http://www.annualcreditreport.com?  Then you can find out for yourself how it's affecting your credit score and track exactly what that is.  Then you're dealing with data instead of opinions.

Comment: From what the OP wrote, it looks like she/he has already obtained her/his credit report and credit score.

Comment: Credit Karma tells you what affects your credit score.